# User edit Profile Form Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-activerecord, erb

I have 2 forms on my user settings page, one for all basic settings, and one for the profile picture. Every time I try to update a users photo I get an error saying "passwords can't be blank" even though the password fields are in a different form.

The code for the forms:

```
<%= form_for @user, :html=> { :multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :email %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :email %>
 </div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
</div>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %><br />
   <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
   </div>
  <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Update" %>
  </div>
 <% end %>

  <%= form_for @user, :html=> { :multipart => true} do |f| %>
<%= f.file_field :photo %>
       <br />
     <%= f.submit "Update" %>
  <% end %>
```

and my user.rb file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :password

  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :photo

    has_attached_file :photo,
                  :styles => {
                  :thumb=> "50x50#",
                  :small  => "220x220>" },
                  :storage => :s3,
                  :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                  :path => "/:style/:id/:filename"

has_many :microposts, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :relationships, :foreign_key => "follower_id",
                           :dependent => :destroy
has_many :following, :through => :relationships, :source => :followed
has_many :reverse_relationships, :foreign_key => "followed_id",
                                   :class_name => "Relationship",
                                   :dependent => :destroy
has_many :followers, :through => :reverse_relationships, :source => :follower

   email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

   validates :name,  :presence => true,
                :length   => { :maximum => 50 }
   validates :email, :presence   => true,
                :format     => { :with => email_regex },
                :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

   validates :password, :presence     => true,
                                       :confirmation => true,
                                       :length       => { :within => 6..40 }

                                        before_save :encrypt_password
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You then need to check if the password field coming blank then ignore the validation and if user fills anything in it, it should be checked and if it's on new record creation, it should be checked always.

So, I would say, it should go like this:

```
validates :password, :presence     => true,
                                       :if => :validate_password?,
                                       :confirmation => true,
                                       :length       => { :within => 6..40 }

def validate_password?
  if new_record?
    return true
  else
    if password.to_s.empty?
      return false
    else
      return true
    end
  end
end
```

also update the method encrypt_password, just add this initial code

```
def encrypt_password
  return if password.to_s.empty?
  ...
  ... existing code
  ... 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your presence validation of your virtual password attribute.

Adding an `:on => create` will stop the validation from firing when you are updating the user.

Try

```
validates_length_of       :password, :length => { :within => 6..40 }, :allow_blank => true
validates_confirmation_of :password
validates_presence_of     :password, :on => :create
```

A nice rails cast is here:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by the sessions?

Comment: Can you show us your encrypt_password method and your controller actions? (based on the comment on the other response) It looks as though you are encrypting an empty password and saving it to the database even when your are not changing your password.

Answer (score 1):

simply editing the password validation with the following should work:

```
validates :password, :presence     => true,
                                       :on => :create,
                                       :confirmation => true,
                                       :length       => { :within => 6..40 }
```

Comment: couldn't get it to work, when I use the edit profile form it wipes the passwords so one can login with a blank password field